# How to Mirrorize Android's Screen?

Tags: java, android, right-to-left, mirror, mirroring

Is there a way to mirror Android screen permanently?

[image: Mirrored screen]

Comment: Maybe you already have an app that does it (I didn't found, searched a lot); maybe you can give me Java code that does this, so I can compile it and use.

Comment: The only thing I've found is `Force RTL layout` function in Android, but it doesn't mirrors the text and works really bad with all apps.

Comment: Beyond the obvious entertainment value, is there any other practical use case for this behavior which would make it harder for the individual to identify icons/text on their screen and/or naviagate?

Comment: You need rooted phone to do this

Comment: @MorrisonChang it's not entertainment for me, this layout is more natural for me as for a left-hander; also I want to practice my mirror reading skill.

Comment: @MorrisonChang it is not an trolling app to prank my friends, if you this about.

Comment: If root isn't an option, you might be able to use the `MediaProjection` API to capture the screen and flip it. For some direction see: [Take a screenshot using MediaProjection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26545970/295004). While there are a number of open source demo projects, the hard part would be the flipping or transform which would probably involve OpenGL ES. Good luck.