# How to take a screenshot in Android with CameraView (SurfaceView)

Tags: android, android-layout, camera, screenshot

I'm trying to take screenshot programmatically of an activity with camera running and an overlay on it.

I have already tried the following :

1. capturing Bitmap and drawing it on a canvas

   The camera part of screen shows up as black
2. using Open GL

   Couldn't get the overlay part of the screen

I also tried to combine both images, that too did't come out well.

NB : I already went through lot of similar questions, but couldn't find a solution for the same.

I'm using Vuforia cloud reco camera in the activity.

Please help me with this, thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to take screen shot of activity?

Comment: Basically I want the user to get an image with content of current screen on pressing a button in the above explained case.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26303163/115145

Answer (score 0):

mSnapshotLayout is getting main layout id whose snapshot you want, Like this

```
mSnapshotLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.snapshotLayout);
```

Use This inside your button click

```
View v1 = mSnapshotLayout.getRootView();
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bm = v1.getDrawingCache();

storeImage(bm);
```

And Here is the method to store that Image

```
@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
private boolean storeImage(Bitmap imageData) {
    // get path to external storage (SD card)
    String iconsStoragePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/Snapshot/";
    File sdIconStorageDir = new File(iconsStoragePath);

    // create storage directories, if they don't exist
    sdIconStorageDir.mkdirs();

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
    String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());

    String filename = "Deal" + currentDateandTime + ".png";

    try {

        File file = new File(sdIconStorageDir.toString() + File.separator
                + filename);

        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(
                fileOutputStream);

        imageData.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);

        bos.flush();
        bos.close();

        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
                new String[] { file.getPath() },
                new String[] { "image/jpeg" }, null);



    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.w("TAG", "Error saving image file: " + e.getMessage());
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.w("TAG", "Error saving image file: " + e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but its not working with WebView. The saved image is a blank one.

Comment: On WbView?? you want WebView Image?

Comment: Yep, my overlay on the cameraview is using a webview. If I can get the image of webview , then I can combine it with camera image which I have saved.

Comment: Can you Show me layout Whose Snapshot You want?

Comment: I'm adding most of the views including webview dynamically using java code, so there no much content in Xml file of the activity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80052/discussion-between-sreejith-k-and-rishi-paul).